# Is there a way to control particle acceleration when using a Curve Guide force?

Tags: particles, force-fields

I know it's possible to control the speed of a particle system affected by a Curve Guide force.

But, is it possible to control the acceleration? It appears that Curve Guide disable other forces but, is there any workaround for this?